# Is it possible to inject a Spring application property value into @Jsonignore annotation?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I would like to let jackson ignore a field depending on a Spring application property. Let me make an example. We have our class `Foo`:

```java
public class Foo {
  @JsonIgnore
  public String bar;
}
```

Let's say, we set an application property as follows:

```
jackson.ignore.foo.bar=false
```

In this case, we do not want `Foo.bar` to be ignored by jackson.

I know that there are Spring annotations that can work with application properties, e.g. the `@Scheduled` annotation can use something like `@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${this.is.an.application.property}")`. But `@JsonIgnore(value = "${jackson.ignore.foo.bar}")` does not work, because it expects a boolean.

Is there some workaround?

Comment: I don't think you can do that since @JsonIngore is not part of the spring annotations. I would consider creating a custom serializer class and then refer your configuration parameters in there and do what ever you want to do